# Programatically add custom domain with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Our app is hosted on app engine; 'myapp.appspot.com'.

It is much like blogger, where each user is given a subdomain.

> So a user Foo has 'foo.myapp.appspot.com'

Now we want that our users should be allowed to add a custom domain to their website.

For instance,

> www.foo.com in place of foo.myapp.appspot.com.

To achieve the same, we need to add zones and CNAME records to the DNS.

> www.foo.com | CNAME | foo.myapp.appspot.com

Now, this doesn't work on app engine because Google doesn't allow creating zones and records programaticaly. A user can only connect a custom domain if the the domain is verified first.

So, is there any way in which we can programatically add zones/records? Or can you please suggest some other way to achieve this workflow?

Thanks.